# Making a multi-part Clonezilla image

Tags: iso-image, clonezilla, disc

I have a clonezilla image for a system that we need to clone, but the USB is broken and we can only use the built in CD/DVD rom. Tried looking through the documentation and not seeing an immediate way to build out a multi part image and I am looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.